# How to store a key value pair field in meteor Collection2

Tags: collections, meteor, meteorite, meteor-collection2

I want to store an array of  key value pair objects . I am using meteor and collection2 . I declared the field data type as given below. I want to store the object like

```
[{key:value,key:value},{key:value,key:value},{key:value,key:value}]
```

In my database schema i defined the schema like this

```
Meteor.mytable = new Meteor.Collection2('mytable', {
    schema: {
        name: {
            type: String,
            label: "name",
            optional:true
        },               
        the_object:{
            type: [Object],
            label:" Storing the list objects ",
            optional:false
        },   
    }
});
```

and while storing the data at server side i am doing

```
Meteor.mytable.insert({name:"name",the_object:[{key:value,key:value},{key:value,key:value}]);
```

But here it is creating an instance which contains only the name field but not the `the_object` filed

Thank you

Comment: read 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/
http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/bson/

Comment: Thanx Denis Nikanorow, I used the Object datatype to store the object field but it is not storing the given object. might be I am doing wrong. I edited the question as per the requirements

Answer (score 0):

In schema you should have to declare key names. The you can store key value pair object in collection2 schema.

```
Meteor.mytable = new Meteor.Collection2('mytable', {
schema: {
    name: {
        type: String,
        label: "name",
        optional:true
    },               
    the_object:{
        type: [Object],
        label:" Storing the list objects ",
        optional:false
    },
    "the_object.$.label": {
        type: String,
        optional: true
    },
    "the_object.$.title": {
       type: String,
       optional: true
    },    
}
});
```

Now you can use insert query as below

```
Meteor.mytable.insert({name:"name",the_object:[{label:value,title:value},{label:value,title:value}]);
Meteor.mytable.insert({name:"name",the_object:[{label:"testLable1",title:"testTitle1"},{label:"testLable2",title:"testTitle2"}]);
```

I am declaring collection2 in mine code as below, see sample code

```
Actions = new Meteor.Collection("actions");

var Schemas = {};
Schemas.Action = new SimpleSchema({
  serviceId: {
    type: String
  },
  actionName: {
    type: String
  },
  actionDescription: {
    type: String
  },
  actionUrl: {
    type: String,
    optional: true
  },
  actionData: {
        type: [Object],
        optional: true
    },
    "actionData.$.label": {
        type: String,
        optional: true
    },
    "actionData.$.require": {
        type: String,
        optional: true
    },
    "actionData.$.name": {
      type: String,
      optional: true
    },
    "actionData.$.placeHolder": {
      type: String,
      optional: true
    },
    "actionData.$.actionType": {
      type: String,
      optional: true
    },
    headers: {
      type: Object,
      optional: true
    }
});

Actions.attachSchema(Schemas.Action);
```

mine query as below

```
Actions.insert({
        serviceId:"123456",
        actionName: "Post",
        actionDescription: "Create a new post on your page.",
        actionUrl: "https://graph.test.com/v2.1/me/feed",
        actionData:
                [
                    {label: "Message", require: "required", name: "message", placeHolder: "Message text"},
                    {label: "Link you want to share", require: "optional", name: "link", placeHolder: "Publicly accessible URL"},
                    {label: "Link name", require: "optional", name: "name", placeHolder: "Title of the link preview"},
                    {label: "Link preview picture", require: "optional", name: "picture", placeHolder: "Preview image associated with the link"},
                    {label: "Link caption", require: "optional", name: "caption", placeHolder: "Caption under the title in the link preview"},
                    {label: "Link description", require: "optional", name: "description", placeHolder: "Description in the link preview"},
                    {label: "Link description", require: "optional", name: "description", placeHolder: "Description in the link preview"}
                ]
    })

Actions.insert({
        serviceId:"123456",
        actionName: "Post",
        actionDescription: "Create a new photo",
        actionUrl: "https://graph.test.com/v2.1/me/photos",
        actionData:
                [
                    {label: "Message", require: "required", name: "message", placeHolder: "Message text"},
                    {label: "Image URL(Publicly accessible URL we can pull the image from.)", require: "required", name: "url", placeHolder: "Publicly accessbile URL of image", actionType: "createfile"}
                ]
    })
```